# If $T^n$ is $q$-contractive, $T$ exactly has one fixed point

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

> > Consider a complete metric space $(X,d)$ and $T\colon X\to X$. Suppose there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the n-th power of $T$ is $q$-contractive. Show that then $T$ has exactly one fixed point $\overline{x}\in X$.

The n-th power is defined inductively:
$$
T^{n+1}(x):=T(T^{n}(x)), n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
And for a function $T\colon X\to X$, $q$-contractive means 
$$
\exists 0\leq q<1~\forall~x,y\in X: d(T(x),T(y))\leq q d(x,y).
$$

---

Now to the proof.

I think I have to show, that $T$ is q-contractive, because then it follows with Banach, that $T$ does have exactly one fixed point. So I have to show, that there exists a $0\leq q<1$ so that for all $x,y\in X$ it is
$$
d(T(x),T(y))\leq q\cdot d(x,y).
$$
And most likely I have to use the q-contractivity of $T^n$, i.e. that there exists a $0\leq q <1$ so that for all $x,y\in X$ it is
$$
d(T^n(x),T^n(y))\leq q\cdot d(x,y).
$$

Can you help me?

Comment: We cannot say that $T$ itself is $q$-contractive.  But what can you say about fixed points of $T$ and fixed points of $T^n$?

Comment: Fixed points of T are fixed points of $T^n$.

Comment: That's a good start because now we know $T$ has at most one fixed point.  Think about the existence of a fixed point of $T$; the list of candidates is short.

Comment: Is it the same fixed point that $T^n$ does have?

Comment: If yes, why? I cannot see it clearly.

Comment: See also: [If $f^N$ is contraction function, show that $f$ has precisely one fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895193/if-fn-is-contraction-function-show-that-f-has-precisely-one-fixed-point),
[Contraction and Fixed Point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525415/contraction-and-fixed-point) and
[To prove : If $f^n$ has a unique fixed point $b$ then $f(b)=b$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854265/to-prove-if-fn-has-a-unique-fixed-point-b-then-fb-b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attempt to show $T$ is $q$-contractive is doomed, as we will show by an example below.

However any fixed point of $T$ is also a fixed point of $T^n$, and there is only one of these.  So if we can show $T$ has a fixed point, we are done.

Let $x \in X$ be the unique fixed point of $T^n$, and consider $T^n(T(x))=T(T^n(x))=T(x)$.  But now $T(x)$ is a fixed point of $T^n$, so $T(x) = x$ and $x$ is also a fixed point of $T$.

---

To show $T$ itself need not be $q$-contractive, consider $T:X\rightarrow X$ on $X=[-1,1]$ defined by $X(x) = |x|$ if $x \lt 0$ and $X(x) = x/2$ if $x \ge 0$.  Then $T^2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$-contractive, but $T$ is not $q$-contractive for any $0 \le q \lt 1$.