# Successive approximation (Banach's fixed point theorem)

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

> > Let (X,d) be a complete metric space and $T\colon X\to X$. Moreover it exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so that the n-th power of $T$ is $q$-contractive. Yesterday my task was to [If $T^n$ is $q$-contractive, $T$ exactly has one fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629098/show-that-t-exactly-has-one-fixed-point). Today my task is the following.

Consider any given $x_0\in X$. Let $\overline{x}\in X$ be the one and only fixed point of $T$ (from the linked task). Show that the sequence of successive approximation
$$
x_m:=T^m(x_0)
$$
converges to $\overline{x}$ and that there is the estimation
$$
d(x_m,\overline{x})\leq q^k\max\limits_{j\in\left\{1,\ldots,n-1\right\}}\left\{d(T^j(x_0),\overline{x})\right\},
$$
whereat $m\in\mathbb{N}$ fullfills
$$
kn\leq m <(k+1)n~\text{for }k\in\mathbb{N}_0:=\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{0\right\}.
$$

---

I only tried to show the convergence yet.

My idea is to assume w.l.o.g. that $n\leq m$ and then using Banach's fixed point theorem, which says that for $j\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and any starting point $x_0\in X$ it is
$$
x_{j+1}:=T^n(x_j)\to \overline{x}.~~~~(*)
$$
So I thought of the following:
$$
x_m=T^m(x_0)=T^n(T^{m-n}(x_0))=T^n(x_{m-n})
$$

and for $m\to\infty$ it is $T^n(x_{m-n})=x_{m-n+1}\to\overline{x}$ because of $(*)$.

Is that okay?

Comment: I am confused about what exactly you are asking. You have proved that $T$ has exactly one fixed point. Hence the sequences starting from $x_0, Tx_0,...,T^{n-1}x_0$ must all converge to this unique fixed point using $T^n$ as the iterator. Hence the sequence starting from $x_0$ using $T$ as an iterator must also converge to the fixed point.

Comment: It is to show that $x_m:=T^m(x_0)$ converges to the fixed point of $T$. I cannot follow your argument.

Comment: Can you explain it?

Comment: I have added a partial answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_m = T^m (x_0)$. Let $\hat{x}$ be the unique fixed point.

Define the sequences $y_k^0 = x_{kn+0}$, $y_k^1 = x_{kn+1}$,all the way to $y_k^{n-1} = x_{kn+n-1}$.

We see that $y_{k+1}^i = T^n(y_k^i)$ for $i=0,...,n-1$, and so we have $y_k^i \to \hat{x}$ for all $i$. It follows that $x_m \to \hat{x}$.

As an aside, since $d(y_k^i ,\hat{x}) \le q^k d( y_0^i , \hat{x} )$, it is straightforward to show the other estimate.

Comment: It's very hard to me to understand what is that defined sequence $y_k^j, j=0,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: $y^0 = (x_0,x_n,x_{2n},x_{3n},...)$, $y^1 = (x_1,x_{n+1},x_{2n+1},x_{3n+1},...)$, etc.

Comment: But what is the intended purpose by using this sequences, I am too stupi.

Comment: You know that $S=T^n$ is a contraction, hence has a unique fixed point. So consider applying $S$ to the $n$ initial points $x_0, T (x_0),...,T^{n-1} (x_0)$. This produces $n$ different sequences, which I have labelled $y^0,...,y^{n-1}$ above. All must converge to the unique fixed point.

Comment: Why do they HAVE to do so?

Comment: Because $S$ is a $q$-contraction and has a unique fixed point.

Comment: I do not understand.. but its my fault. I have to show that $(x_m)=(T^m(x_0))_m$ converges to $\hat{x}$. What has this to do with these $kn\leq m < (k+1)n$? I simply do not understand.

Comment: Do you see that $S$ is a contraction? And that if you apply it to **any** starting point, then it will converge to the unique fixed point?

Comment: Also note that you can write any integer $i$ as $i = k n + m$, where $m \in \{ 0,...,n-1\}$.

Comment: Yes, this follows from Banach. But I do not see why I have to apply $T^n$ on the starting points because i have to show that $x_m$ does converge.

Comment: You need to show that $m \mapsto T^m(x_0)$ converges. One was to do this is to show that $k \mapsto T^{kn+l}(x_0)$ converges for $l=0,...,n-1$. Each of these corresponds to iterating $T^n$ to different starting points ($x_0, T(x_0),...$).

Comment: I have the sequences that you are calling $y^i, i=0,...,n-1$. Each of them converges to $\hat{x}$. Then i pick $x_0$ from $y^0$, $x_1$ from $y^1$ and so on, then $x_n$ from $y^0$ and so on? And this then converges to $\hat{x}$? Thats the idea?

Comment: Sort of. First create the sequence $x_m = T(x_0)$. Note that $x=(x_0,x_1,....) = (y_0^0, y_0^1,...,y_0^{n-1}, y_1^0, y_1^1, y_1^2,..., y_1^{n-1},y_2^0,...)$. Then show that the 'filtered' subsequences $k \mapsto y_k^i$ all converge to the same point, then this implies that $x_k$ converges to the same point.

Comment: In a "picture": When writing the elements of the sequences $y_k^i$ in a column for each sequence, that means: each column converges to $\hat{x}$. The sequence $x_m=T^m(x_0)$ is build by going through the lines from left to right, starting at $y_0^0$ and therefore it converges to $\hat{x}$, too.

Comment: Yes. If every $n$th element of a sequence converges to the same point, then the whole sequence converges to that point. The proof is straightforward: Let $\epsilon>0$, then since each separate subsequence converges, there is some $N_i$ such that the $i$th subsequence is within $\epsilon$ of the limit. Then take $N=\max(N_0,...,N_{n-1})$.

Comment: Could you please have a look on my proof of the estimation? (I post  it as an answer to my question because there is not enough space in a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea for a proof of the estimation.

From the above construction of the series $y^i, i=0,\ldots,n-1$ and the $q$-contractivity of $T^n$ it follows that
$$
d(y_k^i,\overline{x})=d(T^{kn}(y_0^i),T^n(\overline{x}))=d((T^n)^k(y_0^i),T^n(\overline{x}))\\=d((\underbrace{T^n\circ\ldots\circ T^n}_{k-\text{times}})(y_0^i),T^n(\overline{x}))\\\leq q~d((T^n)^{k-1}(y_0^i),\overline{x})=q~d((T^n)^{k-1}(y_0^i),T^n(\overline{x}))\\\leq q^2~d((T^n)^{k-2}(y_0^i),\overline{x})\leq\ldots\\\leq q^k~d(y_0^i,\overline{x}).
$$
Because of $x_m=y_k^i$ for a $i\in\left\{0,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ and a $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ for any $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $y_0^i=T^i(x_0)$ it follows
$$
d(x_m,\overline{x})=d(y_k^i,\overline{x})\leq q^k~d(y_0^i,\overline{x})=q^k~d(T^i(x_0),\overline{x})\\\leq q^k~\max\limits_{j\in\left\{0,\ldots,n-1\right\}}\left\{d(T^j(x_0),\overline{x})\right\}\\\leq q^k~\max\limits_{j\in\left\{1,\ldots,n-1\right\}}\left\{d(T^j(x_0),\overline{x})\right\}.
$$

---

Would be great to hear if this makes sense.

With greetings

math12

Comment: It makes sense, I would write it as follows: $d(y_k^{i+1} ,\hat{x}) = d(T^n(y_k^i) ,T^n(\hat{x})) \le q d(y_k^{i} ,\hat{x})$, from which we have $d(y_k^{i} ,\hat{x}) \le q^n d(y_0^{i} ,\hat{x})$. For the other, write $m=kn+i$, which gives $d(x_m,\hat{x}) = d(y_k^{i} ,\hat{x}) \le q^k d(y_0^{i} ,\hat{x}) \le q^k \max(d(y_0^{0},\hat{x}),...,d(y_0^{n-1},\hat{x}))$, and then substitute the values of $y_0^{i}=T^i(x_0)$.