# To prove : If $f^n$ has a unique fixed point $b$ then $f(b)=b$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, fixed-point-theorems

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a  function such that for some $n_o \in \mathbb N$ , the $n_o$th iterate of $f$ has a unique fixed point $b$ , then how to prove that $f(b)=b$ ? I cant think of anything , please help . Thanks .

Comment: No need to assume continuity, as the answers show.

Comment: A related question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525415/contraction-and-fixed-point

Comment: yes that I see @ l.h.f , Jonas Meyer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: What is

$$f^{n_0}(f(b))\,?$$

Comment: Wow! so we don't actually need continuity ?

Comment: Not if the fixed point of $f^{n_0}$ is unique.

Comment: If $b$ is a fixed point (not necessarily unique) and we assume that $f$ is continuous , then can we show $f(b)=b$ , or atleast that $f$ has a fixed point ?

Comment: If $b$ is a fixed point of $f^{n_0}$, then $f(b)$ is also one. To conclude that $f(b) = b$, some further conditions are required. One sufficient condition is that $f^{n_0}$ has only one fixed point. Other sufficient conditions can involve continuity, although I don't see any such that wouldn't impose a unique fixed point off-hand. However, if $b$ is a fixed point of $f^{n_0}$, and $f$ is continuous, we can deduce that $f$ must have a fixed point, since $b, f(b),\dotsc, f^{n_0-1}(b), f^{n_0}(b) = b$ form a cycle under $f$, and $f(x)-x$ must change sign between some two consecutive points of ...

Comment: these (if $b$ itself is not yet a fixed point).

Answer (score 10):

Suppose that $f(b)=a$.  Then
$$f^{(n_0)}(a)=f^{(n_0)}(f(b))=f^{(n_0+1)}(b)=f(f^{(n_0)}(b))=f(b)=a\ .$$
Thus $a$ is a fixed point of $f^{(n_0)}$, and by assumption $a=b$.