# Attracting Fixed Point Problem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose a complete metric space $M$ and $f:M\rightarrow M$ such that $f^p = f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f$ ($p$ factors) is a contraction, for some $p\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Show that $\exists!a\in M$ such that $f(a) = a$ (a fixed point) and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f^n(x)= a,$$

$\forall x\in M$.

Does anyone know how to solve this exercise?

Comment: As you mentioned, $f^{p}$ is a contraction mapping. This result is known as Banach's fixed-point theorem. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @EkeshKumar, in this case, Banach's theorem gives a fixed point for $f^p$, not immediately for $f$.

Comment: @lhf Oops, you are correct.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854265/to-prove-if-fn-has-a-unique-fixed-point-b-then-fb-b