# If $f^N$ is contraction function, show that $f$ has precisely one fixed point.

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

> If $f$ is a
>   mapping of a complete metric space $(X, d)$ into itself and $f^N$(composite $f$ for $N$ times) is a contraction
>   mapping for some positive integer $N$, then $f$ has precisely one fixed point. (Banach fixed point theorem is applicable)

I tried to show that $f$ is also a contraction function. I considered the sequence $x,f(x),f^2 (x),... $, but then fail pathetically in showing that it's cauchy. Please tell me if my direction is correct, any new ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that $f^N$ has precisely one fixed point?

Comment: ya, directly from Banach fixed point theorem

Comment: See also: [If $T^n$ is $q$-contractive, $T$ exactly has one fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629098/if-tn-is-q-contractive-t-exactly-has-one-fixed-point),
[Contraction and Fixed Point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525415/contraction-and-fixed-point) and
[To prove : If $f^n$ has a unique fixed point $b$ then $f(b)=b$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854265/to-prove-if-fn-has-a-unique-fixed-point-b-then-fb-b)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$f^N$ has  one fixed point $\alpha$, then $f^N(\alpha)=\alpha$ and $f^{N+1}(\alpha)=f(\alpha)$ so $f^N(f(\alpha))=f(\alpha)$, hence $f(\alpha)$ is also a fixed  point. By uniqueness we have $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Comment: It's so simple!!!!