# Suppose $S^m$ is a contraction on a complete metric space $(X,d)$. I want to show that this implies $S$ has a unique fix-point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and let $S: X  \rightarrow X$ be a mapping. Suppose there exist $m \ge 1$ such that $\underbrace {S^m = S \circ S \circ \dots \circ S}_{\text {m times}}$ is a contraction, i.e. there exist $0\le\beta<1$ such that $d(S^m(x),S^m(y)) \le \beta d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

I want to show that this implies that $S$ has a unique fix-point, i.e. there exist a unique $z \in X$ such that $S(z) = z$.

I've tried to apply Banach fix-point theorem which imply that $S^m$ has a unique fix-point. Also, I've tried consider if $S$ has an inverse. Last, I've tried to come up with a proof by contradiction.

Can anyone guide or show how the above could be proven ?

Comment: Investigate the relations between the fixed points of $S$ and of $S^m$.

Comment: But how do I know in the first place that $S$ has a fix-point ?

Comment: You deduce that. First you go hypothetical, "if $x$ is a fixed point of $S$, then ...". Then from what you get, you'll be able to deduce that $S$ has a unique fixed point.

Comment: Show that if $z$ is a fixed point of $S^m$ then $S(z)$ is also a fixed point of $S^m$.

Comment: This is what I've trouble with. I've proved that $S$ has $k\le 1$ fixed points, but having trouble with the existence part.

Comment: Some duplicates and closely related questions: [If $f^N$ is contraction function, show that $f$ has precisely one fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895193/if-fn-is-contraction-function-show-that-f-has-precisely-one-fixed-point),
[If $T^n$ is $q$-contractive, $T$ exactly has one fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629098/),
[Contraction and Fixed Point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525415/) and
[To prove : If $f^n$ has a unique fixed point $b$ then $f(b)=b$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854265/)

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe the existence part was so easy. Now I've tried to come up with so much fancy.